# VBA - Check if data in listobject is filtered

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a custom function to check if the data in a listobject is filtered.

```
Public Function TestFiltered() As Boolean
Dim rngFilter As Range
Dim r As Long, f As Long
Set rngFilter = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
r = rngFilter.Rows.Count
f = rngFilter.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
If r > f Then TestFiltered = True
End Function
```

However I am getting an error "Object variable not set" in `Set rngFilter = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range`

All of my sheets will only have one listobject, but perhaps it is safer to somehow change the function to apply the range for the first listobject found in the activesheet?

Comment: Autofilter is a **method** and does not have a Range property.

Comment: @teylyn - the code above works quite flawlessly, if it is implemented on a worksheet and not on a ListObject. And it refers to Autofilter object, which has a range property - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter.range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of multiplying the columns and the rows and comparing them with `filterArea.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` is rather interesting. This is what I managed to build on it:

```
Public Function TestFiltered() As Boolean

    Dim filterArea As Range
    Dim rowsCount As Long, cellsCount As Long, columnsCount As Long
    Set filterArea = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range

    rowsCount = filterArea.rows.Count
    columnsCount = filterArea.Columns.Count

    cellsCount = filterArea.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

    If (rowsCount * columnsCount) > cellsCount Then
        TestFiltered = True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: thanks viyata, i have tested this and it works as expected. thanks for understanding my problem :)

Comment: nice code, but note: it does *not* work if some row(s) / column(s) are hidden for any other reason than filtering (TestFiltered will return True in that case too).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that tests a specific listobject.  It first uses the ShowAutoFilter property of the ListObject to determine whether the AutoFilter is dislayed.  If so, it then uses the FilterMode property of the AutoFilter object to determine whether it's in filter mode.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim listObj As ListObject

    Set listObj = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1") 'change the sheet and table names accordingly

    If IsListobjectFiltered(listObj) Then
        MsgBox listObj.Name & " is filtered", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox listObj.Name & " is not filtered.", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub


Function IsListobjectFiltered(ByVal listObj As ListObject) As Boolean

    If listObj.ShowAutoFilter Then
        If listObj.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
            IsListobjectFiltered = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    IsListobjectFiltered = False

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try along these lines

```
  Dim i As Long
  Dim isFiltered As Boolean

' test if AutoFilter has been turned on in the active sheet
      If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then 
' loop through the filters of the AutoFilter
        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters 
          For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Item(i).On Then
              isFiltered = True
              Exit For
            End If
          Next i
        End With
      End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work if you are using Tables in Excel. I am using something like this in an If-Then statement to see if the number of rows in the first column matches the number of visible cells in the first column:

```
 Dim tbl As ListObject

 Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

 If tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count <> tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count Then

      'Do something if True

 End If
```