# How to check if a specific filter is applied in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have the following data in a worksheet:
[image]

What I need to do is to check (using VBA) if the following filter is applied to ***Manager*** column:
[image]

so that the data looks like this:
[image]

A bit of research took me to `Worksheets(1).AutoFilterMode`, which only tells if a filter is applied or not.

Finally, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548871/12929167) answer, and tried the following code:

```
Dim datarange as Range

Set datarange = Worksheets("Sales Data").Range("B2:B11")

If testrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count = 4 Then
    ' some code
End If
```

For now it works perfectly. I know this is not a perfect solution. It won't work if the data is changed. Is there any way I can check if the *Manager* column is filtered by *Manager 1*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something similar

```
Sub TestFilter()

    Dim I As Long
    
    With Worksheets(1).AutoFilter
        For I = 1 To .Filters.Count
            If .Filters(I).On Then
                MsgBox "Column: " & I & "; Criteria1: " & .Filters(I).Criteria1
            End If
        Next I
    End With
    
End Sub
```

It works well if you only have one criteria, otherwise the statement

```
             MsgBox "Column:" & I & "; Criteria1:" & .Filters (I) .Criteria1
```

will cause a runtime error.

To get the column header you can use

```
                MsgBox "Column: " & .Range(1, I) & "; Criteria1: " & .Filters(I).Criteria1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/63494607/9439330 for criteria2 (an operator indicates second criteria)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I know, but if the specified conditions are 3 or more, Criteria1 becomes an Array and the statement I mentioned would result in a runtime error.
Working code should be more elaborate, but I wanted to show a simple example.