# Apply filter in Excel with vertically merged cells across several rows

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am looking for a work-around using VBA, so I can handle vertically merged cells across rows with AutoFilter.

I have a table with the following data:

| LPAR | CEC | Environment |  | 27-Dec | 26-Dec | 23-Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcact11 | A8241 | Production | CPU Mean | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
|  |  |  | CPU Max | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
|  |  |  | Mem | 15 | 15 | 15 |
|  |  |  | %Mem Max | 68.2% | 68.2% | 68.2% |
| abccdc12 | B8242 | Production | CPU Mean | 1.9 | 0.9 | 1.3 |
|  |  |  | CPU Max | 2.4 | 2.4 | 2.4 |
|  |  |  | Mem | 32 31 | 34 |  |
|  |  |  | %Mem Max | 26.7% | 25.8% | 28.3% |
| abccdc13 | A8241 | Production | CPU Mean | 1.9 | 0.9 | 1.3 |
|  |  |  | CPU Max | 2.4 | 2.4 | 2.4 |
|  |  |  | Mem | 32 31 | 34 |  |
|  |  |  | %Mem Max | 26.7% | 25.8% | 28.3% |

I want all the data in columns D - G to show when the value in col A (or B or C) is filtered.

I added the following hidden "helper" columns with the missing data:

| LPAR | CEC | Environment | LPAR | CEC | Environment |  | 27-Dec | 26-Dec | 23-Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcact11 | A8241 | Production | abcact11 | A8241 | Production | CPU Mean | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
|  |  |  | abcact11 | A8241 | Production | CPU Max | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
|  |  |  | abcact11 | A8241 | Production | Mem | 15 | 15 | 15 |
|  |  |  | abcact11 | A8241 | Production | %Mem Max | 68.2% | 68.2% | 68.2% |
| abccdc12 | B8242 | Production | abccdc12 | B8242 | Production | CPU Mean | 1.9 | 0.9 | 1.3 |
|  |  |  | abccdc12 | B8242 | Production | CPU Max | 2.4 | 2.4 | 2.4 |
|  |  |  | abccdc12 | B8242 | Production | Mem | 32 31 | 34 |  |
|  |  |  | abccdc12 | B8242 | Production | %Mem Max | 26.7% | 25.8% | 28.3% |
| abccdc13 | A8241 | Production | abccdc13 | A8241 | Production | CPU Mean | 1.9 | 0.9 | 1.3 |
|  |  |  | abccdc13 | A8241 | Production | CPU Max | 2.4 | 2.4 | 2.4 |
|  |  |  | abccdc13 | A8241 | Production | Mem | 32 31 | 34 |  |
|  |  |  | abccdc13 | A8241 | Production | %Mem Max | 26.7% | 25.8% | 28.3% |

I was trying to capture the user filter in the Calculate event, and if one of A/B/C had been filtered, remove that filter and apply the filter to the corresponding helper column of D/E/F.  I am having problems:

1. getting the filter applied to col a/b/c in a manner that I could apply it to  D/E/F
2. once I either remove the filter or add a filter in the change event, it doesn't come back to execute the next line (at least not in the debugger).

I know I am not the first person who needs to filter on a vertically merged cell across rows.  I would appreciate help allowing me how to accomplish this.

Comment: you may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976019/how-to-check-if-a-specific-filter-is-applied-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: It turns out applying the filtering to the hidden helper columns isn't a great solution for the overall problem.  It works fine on the original filter, but if the user wants to refilter it again, because the filter is now applied to the helper column, only the filtered values are available for the filter, not the whole list that needs to be available for a refilter.
For my 2nd attempt at solving my overall problem, I will try removing all the merged cells, and use formatting and changing the font color to white on all cells and remove grid lines on all but the cell in the vertical center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a comment to point you to how to detect the filtered column, but leaving the "how to detect the filter applying" uncovered

As per my experience you have to:

A- use a helper cell to place a counter of visible cells along a column

for instance I shifted data one row down and used cell "D1" (just above "LPAR") to host `=SUBTOTAL(3;D2:D1000)` formula

this will give you a hook that would trigger the `Worksheet_Calculate()` event

B- add the following code to the worksheet code pane

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    
    If Me.FilterMode Then

        Dim msg As String
        Dim filters() As TFilter
            If GetFilteredColumns(Me, _
                                  filters) Then
                
                Dim iFilter As Long
                    For iFilter = 1 To UBound(filters)
                        With filters(iFilter)
                            msg = msg & _
                                  "filtered field: " & .iFilter _
                                   & vbLf & vbTab & "Criteria: " _
                                   & vbLf & vbTab & vbTab & Join(.criteriaarray, vbLf & vbTab & vbTab) _
                                   & vbLf & vbTab & "operator: " & .operator _
                                   & vbLf & vbLf
                        End With
                    Next
                
            Else
                msg = "No filters!"
            End If
            
    Else
    
        msg = "No filters!"
        
    End If
        
        MsgBox msg
    
End Sub
```

C- add the following code in a new Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Type TFilter
    iFilter As Long
    criteriaarray As Variant
    operator As XlAutoFilterOperator
End Type


Function GetFilteredColumns(sh As Worksheet, _
                            filters() As TFilter) As Boolean
    
        With sh
            If .FilterMode Then ' at least one filter is on
            
                With .AutoFilter
                    ReDim filters(1 To .filters.Count) As TFilter
                    Dim nFilters As Long
                    Dim iFilter As Long
                    For iFilter = 1 To .filters.Count
                        With .filters(iFilter)
                            If .On Then
                            
                                Dim criteria As Variant
                                nFilters = nFilters + 1
                                
                                    filters(nFilters).iFilter = iFilter
                                    filters(nFilters).operator = .operator
                                    
                                    Select Case .Count
                                        Case 1
                                            ReDim criteria(1 To 1)
                                                criteria(1) = .Criteria1
                                        Case 2
                                            ReDim criteria(1 To 2)
                                                criteria(1) = .Criteria1
                                                criteria(2) = .Criteria2
                                        Case Else
                                            criteria = .Criteria1
                                    End Select
                                        filters(nFilters).criteriaarray = criteria
                                
                            End If
                        End With
                    Next
                    
                End With
                
                ReDim Preserve filters(1 To nFilters) As TFilter

                GetFilteredColumns = True
                
            End If
            
        End With
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you!  With your help, I got the set filter on the helper columns.   However, my approach still isn't great, because the user can't re-filter on the display column - with the filter on the helper column, only those filtered selections are available for selection for the filter, not the whole list.  But thank you, your answer was exactly what I asked and it works. Unfortunately, I will have to try another solution for my overall problem. Next attempt: I will try leaving all the cells separate, but use conditional formatting to change the font color to make it appear "merged".

Comment: You are welcome. And I agree that merged cells are the devil!

Comment: BTW you may want to accept the solution. Thanks